# Would site design questions be a good fit for Pro Webmasters?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, design

I'm struggling to find the right site to ask web site design related questions.  Pro Webmasters tends to be more about technical questions, but the faq for Pro Webmasters indicates that questions that are relative to the entire site are appropriate.  Site design seems like it would fall under that category (ie questions about layout, flow, design issues, tempating/master pages, etc..)

I guess i'm looking for something like Programmers.SE but more oriented around issues dealing with the design of sites (ie sites that allow subjective questions and answers, because design tends to be a very subjective subject.)

So I guess what i'm asking is if Pro Webmasters is the right place, or if you would suggest a different place in the SE hierarchy, or somewhere totally different.

Comment: *Some* (but perhaps not all) of those would be welcome on [graphicdesign.se] I'm sure.

Comment: @Aarthi - Thank you.  Yes, good point.  It's frustrating though, since we have so many specialist sites that doen't really allow you to put all the pieces together.  We have a Web Applications site, a Pro WebMasters Site, A programmers site, SO, etc.. But overall design questions are off topic for all of them.  I hate to propose YET ANOTHER specialist site on area 51, particularly when it would also cover so many topics of the other specialist sites.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer i'm looking for is the User Experience SE Site, which seems to cover most of the issues i'm looking for.  Perhaps adding ux.stackexchange.com to the FAQ for design questions might be a good idea.